# Vue.js Vuex State Never Updates With push()

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a Vuex store that manages an array (`state.all`), and I have a button that calls a Vuex action which performs an HTTP call and then appends the the data in the response to `state.all` by way of a mutation. However, the state never gets updated and the components never update.

In order prove that I was not crazy, I used two `alert()`s inside of the mutation to make sure I knew where I stood in the code. The `alert()`s were always fired with proper values.

Here is the truncated Vuex store (this is a module):

```
const state = {
    all: []
}

// actions
const actions = {
    ...
    runner ({ commit, rootState }, { did, tn }) {
       HTTP.post(url, payload)
           .then(function (response) {
               commit('setNewConversations', response.data)
           })
       })
    }
}

const mutations = {
    ...
    setNewConversations(state, new_conv) {
        for (let new_c_i in new_conv) {
            let new_c = new_conv[new_c_i]
            alert(new_c) // I always see this, and it has the correct value
            if (!(new_c in state.all)) {
                alert('I ALWAYS SEE THIS!') // testing
                state.all.push(new_c)
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

When I go to test this, I see my two `alert()`s, the first with the value I expect and the second with "I ALWAYS SEE THIS!" but nothing happens to my `v-for` component and the state never updates, despite the `state.all.push()`.

What is the next step to troubleshooting this issue? There are no errors in the JS console, and I cannot figure out any reason the state would not be updated.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure it's not updating the store? Maybe for some reason the view is just not updating?

Comment: Now when I remove my `alert()`, it suddenly starts working. This is now an issue that only happens occasionally. What could I do to figure out why this is happening?

Comment: Do you have `vue devtools` extension/plugin/whatever in your browser installed, it's a great way to monitor your vuex state

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is instead of pushing to the current state value, store the previous value of `state.all` in a new array and push the new changes to that new array.

Once done, assign that new array to `state.all` like the following below.

```
 setNewConversations(state, new_conv) {
    const prevState = [...state.all];
    for (let new_c_i in new_conv) {
        let new_c = new_conv[new_c_i]
        if (!(new_c in prevState)) {
          prevState.push(new_c);
        }
    }
    state.all = prevState;
}
```

Comment: Why in the world would I use a `const` in this particular situation?

Comment: @David why not? You can push things to a const array, you know

Comment: @downvoter, I don't really mind the downvote but I would appreciate if you leave a comment/reason of the downvote so I could also learn and not make the same mistake next time. @David, you can modify an array declared `const` as long as yo don't reassign it.

Comment: @AnaLizaPandac not sure why you were downvoted, someone must not understand vue/javascript, because this is indeed the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Given that you said that removing the alert makes it work makes me wonder if you are just observing the value in the wrong place.  I can't be sure from what you've given.

Remember that Javascript is single-threaded, and your mutation has to complete before any other Vue-injected reactivity code can run.

If you really wanted the value to be shown before the mutation is complete, you could probably call `Vue.nextTick(() => alert(...))`, but the better answer is to check for the updates somewhere else, such as in a computed that calls the getter for the state.all array.

(By the way, I find that using either `console.log(...)` or the vue-dev-tools is much faster than `alert()` for arbitrary debugging.)